# Vastly Overzealous GC on Android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I'm developing a game for Android, and am having huge (and unpredictable) issues with the garbage collector.

During one phase of loading, we allocate about 18,000 1616 byte arrays (some chunked up level data). Sometimes, but not always, the garbage collector will decide to run a sweep after every single allocation, slowly increasing the heap size:

```
06-13 13:51:59.362  16941-17640/com.lp.aeronautical.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 17% free 41923K/50472K, paused 191ms, total 191ms
06-13 13:51:59.362  16941-17640/com.lp.aeronautical.android I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 43.037MB for 1616-byte allocation
06-13 13:51:59.536  16941-17640/com.lp.aeronautical.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 17% free 41926K/50476K, paused 174ms, total 174ms
06-13 13:51:59.536  16941-17640/com.lp.aeronautical.android I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 43.040MB for 1616-byte allocation
06-13 13:51:59.765  16941-17640/com.lp.aeronautical.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 17% free 41931K/50480K, paused 179ms, total 179ms
```

repeated for all 18,000 allocations. Needless to say this is horrid and makes the game chug badly for a few minutes.

Is there some way to reel in the GC on Android?  Or perhaps at least make it grow the heap in larger chunks? (which it normally does just fine).

Comment: "Is there some way to reel in the GC on Android?" -- among other things, don't try allocating 18,000 1,616-byte arrays individually. For starters, you won't have enough heap space for that on lots of devices. That is ~28MB, and your heap limit may be less than that, or only slightly more than that.

Comment: Well, we're using far more than that in other costs -- we're not targeting all devices, only high end ones.  For instance, we've got about 20-30mb of music resources at any given time.

The reason I'm allocating so many arrays is to save space. I only want to allocate as much memory as needed, and there doesn't seem to be any way to re-size arrays. Since I don't know how much memory I need ahead of time, I chunk it up and allocate as necessary.

Comment: "there doesn't seem to be any way to re-size arrays" -- yes, Java arrays (`[]` notation) cannot be resized. "Since I don't know how much memory I need ahead of time, I chunk it up and allocate as necessary" -- then allocate by chunk, not by array (e.g., `new byte[][]`) or something.

Comment: Hmm, what exactly do you mean allocate by chunk?  Currently I've got a `chunks = new int[MAX_CHUNKS][]` and I allocate a new chunk like so `chunks[chunkNum] = new int[CHUNK_SIZE]`. This is done lazily as chunks are needed. Is there some better way to do the allocation?

Comment: But even though these are done lazily, there are still a ton of chunks allocated at the start, causing the GC churn.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I was thinking more C-style allocations with my previous comment, which get more icky in Java -- my apologies. But things will run faster if you can allocate `MAX_CHUNKS*CHUNK_SIZE` bytes once and subdivide that space yourself, again assuming you have the heap for it.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking that's how I might have to do it -- allocate large blocks and then have my own small allocation system within them. :\ Pains of being in a managed language.

Comment: @CommonsWare I figured out a solution -- using ByteBuffer's kept the GC from having to constantly react and expand the heap.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up converting all of the array allocations to ByteBuffers allocated with ByteBuffer.allocateDirect. This meant I was only making 18000 very small Java heap allocations (just pointers basically), and all of the array memory was stored in native memory.

Moving the big allocations to native memory meant the Dalvik GC no longer noticed the allocations as a problem.

Comment: Note, though, that these allocations still count against your heap limit, AFAIK. See: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2367

Comment: Oh, that's really interesting. Perhaps the problem went away just because while it was counted towards the heap, it still didn't need to expand anything. This was actually the perfect article because we're using LibGDX -- that last hack at the bottom would probably fix any further problems right up. :) Thanks!

Comment: "Perhaps the problem went away just because while it was counted towards the heap, it still didn't need to expand anything" -- right. Native allocations are just `malloc()` and `free()`. To keep process sizes in line, they count it against the Dalvik heap, but they are not *allocated* from the Dalvik heap. Note that I would expect that these allocations also will not be counted in heap dumps analyzed with MAT, just as bitmaps used to not show up properly prior to Android 3.0. MAT will count them only for their Java heap use, not also for the size of the backing allocation, I suspect.